# Unable to update the deployed code on google app engine

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I have a Maven project deployed to google app engine on 1.9.25, Last week the app engine changed to 1.9.30 and from then i am unable to deploy the latest code from eclipse. The deployment logs shows "deployed sucessfully"  below is the log. But the latest changes are not getting update. Anyone faced similar issue?

```
------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\RITHVI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg7427034133744005110.tmp'
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Generated git repository information file.
    Scanning files on local disk.
    Initiating update.
    Cloning 3 static files.
    Cloning 168 application files.

Deploying:
    Uploading 0 files.
    Initializing precompilation...
    Deploying new version.
    Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
    Uploading index definitions.

Deployment completed successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

The log shows that no files have been uploaded, which means that from App Engine point of view no files have been changed in your project relative to the copies of these files on App Engine. Try changing a version number for your app, and see if resolves the issue.

NB: All my apps (Java runtime) are being updated with no issues.

Comment: I tried to change the version number also. Still its the same.No change with the new version.

Comment: If you still see "Uploading 0 files.", there is a problem somewhere in your setup. When you change version number, at least one file is changed and should be uploaded. The problem is not on the App Engine side.

Comment: I did a clean install of the eclipse and maven when i tried to deploy the same code with new version, i see the below details and when i went to the server i dont see the new Version  at all. also when i tried to update the previous version same message but version is not updated at all
Uploading 2 files.Uploaded 1 files.Uploaded 2 files.Initializing precompilation...Sending batch containing 1 file(s) totaling14KB.Sending batch containing 1 blob(s) totaling 14KB. ........Deployment completed successfully